# Evaluating $\lim _{x\to \infty }\tan\left(x^2\sin\frac{\pi }{4x^2}\right)$ without L'hopital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

How do I solve this without using L'hopital's rule?

$$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\tan\left(x^2\sin\left(\frac{\pi }{4x^2}\right)\right)\right)$$

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJ9nh.png)

EDIT:
My progress so far:

$$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\tan\left(x^2\sin\left(\frac{\pi }{4x^2}\right)\right)\right)$$

$$=\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\tan\left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi }{4x^2}\right)}{\frac{1}{x^2}}\right)\right)$$

$$=\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}*\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi }{4x^2}\right)}{\frac{\pi}{4x^2}}\right)\right)$$

Now I know $\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{x} = 1$ but I don't know how to take the above expression to that form.

Comment: Hi there! I'm more than happy to give you a hand, but I want to (1) avoid writing a solution that contains "redundant" details (e.g. repeating a part of the solution process you've already made progress on and/or clearly understand), and (2) avoid revealing the answer to a homework problem unless I know you've put some effort into solving it. Could you be kind enough to show how you've attempted to attack the problem?

Comment: @AlannRosas, hey, nice approach! this is different from the usual copy paste of rep-w users

Comment: Hints: change of variable $t:=\dfrac{\pi}{4x^2}$ and continuity of the tangent.

Comment: Write down the Taylor series and take the limit as x goes to infinity.

Comment: @AlannRosas I have made my edits to my original post to show my progress. I appreciate that you are not blindly handing out solutions and allowing the OPs to actually work on their problems. This was my first time posting on math.stackexchange.com so I didn't know how to go about it. From now on, I'll ask questions along with my progress so far.

Comment: @MSha Taylor series is a overkill for someone who has just started out with limits, we all should try to answer in a way which is understandable for the OP according to their current knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already taken care of one important bit, namely rewriting

$$\tan\left(x^2\sin\frac{\pi}{4x^2}\right)$$

as

$$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\cdot\frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{4x^2}}{\frac{\pi}{4x^2}}\right)$$

As you noted, $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$, so we should make use of this somehow. We can achieve this goal by making use of another important observation, namely that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\pi}{4x^2}=\frac{\pi}{4}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}=\frac{\pi}{4}\cdot 0=0$$

Knowing this, I hope it makes sense that we should have

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4x^2}\right)}{\frac{\pi}{4x^2}}=1$$

After all, as $x$ gets bigger and bigger, $\frac{\pi}{4x^2}$ gets closer and closer to $0$, and $\sin(y)/y$ gets closer and closer to $1$ as its argument gets smaller and smaller, namely $y=\frac{\pi}{4x^2}$.

Alright, so we know that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4x^2}\right)}{\frac{\pi}{4x^2}}=1$$

and thus, by the constant multiple rule for limits

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\cdot\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4x^2}\right)}{\frac{\pi}{4x^2}}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

But the tangent function $\tan$ is continuous near $\pi/4$, so

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\cdot\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4x^2}\right)}{\frac{\pi}{4x^2}}\right)=\tan\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\cdot\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4x^2}\right)}{\frac{\pi}{4x^2}}\right)\right)=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=1$$

We conclude that the original limit is

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\tan\left(x^2\sin\frac{\pi}{4x^2}\right)=1$$

Comment: $\tan$ is not continuous in $\mathbb{R}$. It's just that $x^{2}\sin(\frac{\pi}{4x^{2}})$ takes values within $(-\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4})$ within which tan is continuous . You should edit that.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron you’re right! I have fixed that part of the proof :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$\lim _{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ then if $x\to\infty\ $ means $\frac{1}{x}\to0$. So basically $\lim _{x\to \infty} \frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\frac{1}{x}}$ is also equal to $1$